# Keep focus on Textbox after pressing enter in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems with losing focus on textbox when pressing enter. I know there is a similar question already solved, but it just doesn't work for some reason.

This code detects an enter pressed while in the `MeasuredDim` textbox and then calls the `NextDim_click` sub. `NextDim_click` also works through a commandbutton and has also `MeasuredDim.SetFocus` included and it works fine through the button press, but when calling `NextDim_click` after Enter press, the focus is lost on the whole UserForm.

How is it not working for me?

```
 Private Sub MeasuredDim_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
    Call NextDim_Click
    KeyCode = 0
    MeasuredDim.SetFocus
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What similar question doesn't work for what reason?

Comment: Referring to this one  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685661/keep-focus-on-textbox-after-pressing-enter[link]

Answer (score 0):

This works for  me:

```
Private Sub MeasuredDim_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Call NextDim_Click
        KeyCode = 0
        Me.MeasuredDim.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NextDim_Click()
    MsgBox "NextDim_Click"
End Sub
```

Notice the line

```
Me.MeasuredDim.SetFocus
```

where the `Me` keyword fully qualifies the statement.